# How to recreate this table in windows form?

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, windows-forms-designer

I need an idea about how to recreate this table in windows form.

[image: Table]

"x11" and "c11" are both integers and i have to be able to access them both by their indexes.

I also must be able to select portions of the table, something like

[image: this]

and to draw lines on multiple cells like

[image: this].

I have few ideas in my head, from using panels to TableLayoutPanel but i don't really know what to follow.

How do you think i should do that? All i need is a detailed idea.

Thank you!!

Comment: Never create your own grid control, especially not from TableLayoutPanel.  Lots of them around, two are readily available in the toolbox.  ListView with View=Details, you'd consider using its OwnerDraw property to make the grid content look the way you want it.  DataGridView is the more powerful one, also allows data entry, CellPainting event to customize appearance.

Comment: Tell us more about the functionality! Is there any? User interaction (beyond the selection)? Control hosting? Making DGV or LV draw themselves like this is also work but the other things may make the difference..

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for your idea, i will try to make a custom control with 2 textboxes or something and add them to a datagrid. i still have to figure out the selecthing thing.

Comment: @TaW the user should be able to edit the integers i spoke about, that's all. the selection will be made within the code.

Comment: [Hosting in a DGV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells) is not simple as this tutorial will show you. Any other panel, esp. a FlowLayoutPanel will be easier to host a grid of UCs.

Comment: @TaW: But provides no selection capability whatsoever.  DataGridView will be the easiest way to do this.  Especially since I don't see anything here that requires hosting an actual window, simply custom drawing the cells will be enough.

Comment: @Ben: I see the requirement to have two textboxes in each cell. If selection is just about drawing some rectangles or lines  or maybe changing the backcolor of a range of UCs, it is easy..

Comment: @TaW: Alternatively, every second column is rendered using a smaller font size, and the column headers span 2.  Easy peasy with DataGridView.

Comment: Sounds doable but not easy peasy imo but messy. No col- or rowspan really, disrupted layout. UCs look a  lot cleaner, but in the end one would have to try. I don't have the time atm